# video frames extraction code running error

Tags: c#, video, frames, extract

i found an article on this site  **http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9676/Extracting-still-pictures-from-movie-files-with-C**

about video frames extraction.
i am trying to run the source code given here..
i created a new project added the given C# code in it.
then i added the given reference " interop.dexterlib.dll" in it.

it gives an error about MediaDetClass.
Error   1
Interop type 'DexterLib.MediaDetClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.
 i am not getting it how to solve this. please help.

Comment: I suspect that you're referencing it in an application with .Net4.0 or higher, change your target framework to `.Net3.5` and your platform target to `x86`, then it should work.

Comment: yes i had solved it . thank you.